# How to make element fit the parent width CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build an HTML UI.

Here's what I've done:

[image: what I've done]

The width of the parent `div` is auto changing to contain all the buttons inside it.

For example, when there are 3 buttons:

[image: three buttons]

I'm trying to add an option to add a button. I added a text box and a save button after the buttons.

[image: with text box]

But for some reason, the text box takes a lot of width and makes the parent grow.

How can I make the text box width be as the parent's width?

my code:

```
<div id="savedSets" class="cotentBox" style="margin-right: auto; margin-left: auto;max-width: 90%; display: table;">
  <h3 class="header">Use saved sets</h3>

  <div class="content">
    <div id="setButtons">
      <button class="button savedSetButton">Set 2</button>
      <button class="button savedSetButton">Set 1</button></div>
    <div id="newSet">
      <button id="saveNewSet" class="button">Save new set!</button>
     <input type="text" id="newSetName">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add a sketch of the desired result? Also depending on the browsers you'd want to support [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) might do what you want.

Comment: The element's (and the parent's) properties, especially margin / padding / border / ... play all a role here. Without an example to reproduce your problem it's almost impossible to answer your question.

Comment: I added my code. (edited)

Answer (score 0):

`textarea` width `100%` works fine try,

```
    <div id="savedSets" class="cotentBox" style="max-width: 90%; display: table;border:1px solid black;margin:auto">
  <h3 class="header">Use saved sets</h3>

  <div class="content">
    <div id="setButtons" style="float:left;padding-right:4px">
      <button class="button savedSetButton">Set 2</button>
      <button class="button savedSetButton">Set 1</button></div>
    <div id="newSet">
      <button id="saveNewSet" class="button" style="float:left">Save new set!</button>
     <input type="text" id="newSetName" style="width:100%;border:none">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```